# Python negative index?

Tags: python, encoding, brackets

I have simple question about prisoners dilemma. It is mainly just to reassure that I am doing this correctly.

In the code below [-1] means that it will see if your last move is collude and if their last move is betray. And you could go even further back in the histories using [-2] or [-3]

```
elif my_history[-1]=='c' and their_history[-1]=='b':
    return 'b'
else:
    return 'c'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question has nothing to do with Prisoner's Dilemma, I've retitled it to reflect what appears to be your actual question. I've also removed the `canopy` tag since this question seems to be strictly about pure Python (a very active topic here), nothing specifically about Canopy.

If your question is "does `history[-1]` yield the last element of the `history` list", then the answer is Yes. You can verify this at the Python prompt with something like this:

`history = list('abcde')
print history
print history[-1]`

Comment: thank you! Thats what I was wondering about, and this code comes from an assignment on Prisoners Dilemma which our class is currently using enthought canopy to code to clarify, but thank you for all the help.

Comment: Glad this helped.
a) Please read and act on these guidelines: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work
b) Yes, I understood that you were using this as part of a Prisoner's Dilemma coding project. But your question is not at all specific to that. The title of a question should reflect the content of a question, not the reason you are asking it. As an analogy, if you wanted information about making an apple pie for your friend's birthday, you would probably google "good type of apple for pies" rather than "help with birthday".